# Retrieve Least Element, Elements are Dynamically-Ordered

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have collection of elements from which I need to retrieve the least/minimum element.

Normally I would use a PriorityQueue as they are designed specifically for this purpose, and offer O(log(n)) time for dequeing methods.

However, the elements in my array have a dynamic order, ie there natural order changes unpredictably over time. I *assume* PriorityQueue and other such Sorted collections sort an element when inserted, and then leave it. If this is so PriorityQueue wouldn't work for dynamically-ordered elements. Am I correct in my assumption? Or would PriorityQueue still be appropriate in this situation?

If I can't use PriorityQueue, Collections.min would be my next instinct. However this iterates over the entire collection, which presumably gives O(n) time. Is this the next best solution?

**What is the best collection/method to use to retrieve the least element from a collection, given that the natural order of the elements may change unpredictably over time?**

Edit:
The order of several elements changes per retrieval operation

Edit 2:
The compare algorithm remains constant, however the values of the fields which it assesses vary unpredictably between retrievals.

Comment: You could try creating a PriorityQueue with a Comparator and include the time depending sort order logic in the Comparator. I can't tell you how the PriorityQueue will behave, but maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: This would be perfect if the order was some function of time, however it's not that predictable. I've edited the question to make this clearer. Thanks

Comment: how often will the order change compared to extracting minimum?

Comment: It wouldn't work: collections work under the assumption that `compare(a, b)` is constant for each <a, b>; if you change the behaviour under it's nose it's just going to start ordering the newly-inserted elements in the now-correct place, but it won't move those that are already present. It's telling that you cannot change a sorted collection's `Comparator` after you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the change is truly "unpredictable" you may be stuck with Collections.min().  However, maybe for some other collections like PriorityQueue you could try, before calling for the min.

1. Add something that you KNOW is the min.
2. Remove that
3. Then ask again for the "real" min and hope that your little kludge resorted things...

Alternatively, do you know if the order has changed over time?  e.g. some OrderChangedEvent can be fired?  If so, recreate the sorted whatever as needed.

Comment: Why should that solution have any beneficial effect in his (or any other) case?

Comment: +1 for suggesting a listener/event model, which I was about to add myself. However, if your add-new-min-element/remove-min 'klugde' works, then it requires PriorityQueue to iterate over the collection to find the min after every retrieval, same as Collections.min(). If you agree to might want to edit that part out, as the rest of your answer is good.

Comment: @Aaron  I looked at the PriorityQueue source code the other day, and it has some sort of internal "balanced binary heaps".  I have to claim ignorance of the details, (ultimately methods `siftUp` or `siftDown` get called) but it seems to me that those are partially sorted, in which case the kludge is possibly faster than O(n).  And, I did call it a kludge!  I really don't know if it will work, but it would be worth a quick try.

Comment: @Aaron as for the event model, note that you don't need to resort on every event, just if there has been one or more events since the last time.  So it's more of a repaint() type call - you can "stack up" and ignore multiple events.

Comment: @Aaron (sorry, I don't see a way on this browser to edit my comments) you might need to test for the equivalent of a ConcurrentModificationException if you get an event in the middle of re-sorting.

Comment: @user949300 For a moment, let's assume your kludge doesn't work. The only way to reorder elements is to remove incorrect ones, and re-add them, at which point they'll be inserted in the right place. In order to remove the elements, PriorityQueue has to find them. If it assumes that they're sorted (which they aren't) and does a binary search, it will malfunction.

Comment: cont. If it doesn't assume they're sorted, and iterates over the collection to find the object and remove it this will be O(n). On average it will only have to iterate over half the collection, but will have to do this for each removal, of which there will be several. At this point Collections.min() is more efficient.
So really unless the kludge works, and works with low complexity, I don't think this can be more efficient. Brilliant idea tho, thanks for all the time and effort :) I think the easiest way to test the kludge would be to implement it & Collections.min(), and profile both.

Comment: Frankly, the more I think about it, the more I agree with you, and doubt that the kludge will work.  If you test it and it does profile faster than Collections.min(), please report back!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this would be to extend `PriorityQueue` that contains a list as one of the fields. This list will store the `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` of each object. Whenever an add, peek, poll, offer, etc. is called on the `PriorityQueue`, the queue will check the hash codes of each element and make see if any element changed. If they have, it will re-order the elements that have changed. Then, it will replace the hashcodes of the changed elements in the list. I don't know how fast this will be, but I suspect it will be faster than O(n).

Comment: His problem is that the whole ordering changes, not only the value of single elements.

Comment: +1 For almost a listener/event model, but without having to fire propertyChangeEvents. Changes are detected via hashCode(). Would reordering require removing & re-adding the element? Remove & add would probably both use a binary search, which I think is O(log(n))?

Comment: @Viruzzo sorry for confusion, see Edit 2

Comment: Hang on, if we're iterating over the collection to check hashes, we might as well just iterate over and check compareTo, ie Colletions.min() . That's assuming hash is as complex an operation as CompareTo, which it will have to be to include all the fields that compareTo checks.

Answer (score 1):

**Without any further assumption on the operations you are going to do**, you can't achieve better performance than with a `PriorityQueue` or another O(log(n))-insert collection (TreeSet , for example, but you lose the O(1)-peek).
As you correctly assumed `Collections.min(Collection, Comparator)` is a linear operation.

**But** it depends on how often you need to change the ordering: for example if you only need to change it once in a while and still keep a "standard" ordering, `min()` is a viable option, but if you need to switch ordering completely then you will probably be better off with reordering the queue/set (that is, traversing and adding all the elements in a new one), tough at a O(nlog(n)) cost. Using `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` may be effective if you need a lot of reordering compared to inserts, but requires you to use a `List`.

Of course if you can make somewhat strong assumptions on the types of sorting you will need (for example, if it can be restricted to a part of the data) you could write your own collection.

**Edit:**
So you have a (more or less) finite number of orderings (never mind that it's the same type of comparison over different fields, it's different Comparators and that's what matters)? If that's the case, you can probably achieve best performance by using m queues that reference the same objects, each using a different comparator (the simplest method, really). This way you have:

- constant time access
- O(m*logn(n)) inserts (to insert in every queue)
- O(m*n) removals (to remove from every queue)
- no ordering costs (as it's handled by the inserts)
- slightly larger memory cost (probably negligible)
- additional O(n*log(n)) cost the first time a particolar ordering is requested

Supposing a value of m orders of magnitude smaller than n, this is comparable to optimal (single-ordering PriorityQueue) performance. For convenience, you can wrap this into a custom collection that takes a Comparator parameter on retrieval operations, and use it as a key for an HashMap of all the PriorityQueues.

**Edit #2:**
In that case, there is no better solution than running min() on every retrieval (unless you can make assumptions on the changes of the data); this also means that it's better to just use an ArrayList as the collection, since it has basically the lowest possible cost on every operation and you will not benefit from PriorityQueue's natural ordering anyway. You will end up with linear cost on retrieval (for min) and constant on insertion and deletion: this is optimal as there is no sorting algorithm that has less than Ω(n) and Θ(nlog n) anyway.

As a side note, ordered collections work on the assumption that values will not change after insertion; this is because there is no cost-effective way to monitor the changes nor to reorder them "in place".

Comment: I'm not really looking for better performance than PriorityQueue, _if_ PriorityQueue will work given a dynamic ordering. Your second paragraph is a little hard to follow. Could you summarise in light of edits 1&2? Thanks

Comment: Your solution is ingenious, but I still don't think I've explained myself properly. The comparator is singular and constant. It assesses the same fields every time. However, the values in those fields (ie the state of the elements) change over time.

Comment: Thank you very much :) It's a shame I can't accept two answers

Comment: Never you mind. It's rather interesting analyzing the different collections and algorithms for non-obvious situations.

Comment: Wouldn't linkedList be better? Iteration should be almost identical to arrayList, but removal would be faster wouldn't it? (I realise I didn't specify I was removing the min element in the question)

Comment: LinkedList's disadvantage lies in the random access cost, but since you traverse the whole thing with min() yes, it would be roughly equivalent to using an ArrayList; it becomes a tradeoff for very slight differences in usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a java TreeSet which keeps the collection sorted at all times. You need to implement the Comparable interface on your objects to do so. Checkout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: His problem is that the ordering changes over time; if not, by using PriorityQueue he would have had better performance anyway.

Comment: So I add two Siblings, Jack (aged 9) and Jill (aged 10), to a TreeSet. Siblings natural order is based on age, so treeSet.first should return  Jack. If I change Jack's add to 11 _after_ he is added to the TreeSet, will first() now return Jill? How does TreeSet know the correct order has changed?

Comment: It doesn't. Keep in mind that basic types in Java are immutable, so you can't change the value of the object inside the set.

Comment: Primitives are immutable. I wouldn't try to mutate the int to a different value, I would simply assign it a different value, ie Jack.age = 11;

Comment: So, if it is age that we are worried about, wouldn't everyone age at the same pace? Which means, you would mutate everyone with the same factor. No?